# Rounding a raster to the hundredths place in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-pro, raster-calculator

I'm trying to round a raster with only positive values to the hundredths place in ArcGIS Pro. I found two formulas here on the Stack that would successfully round some of the values and others they would not. One of my values would round to 26.980000 and then another would round to 27.540001. I don't know why the rounding works some of the time.

[image] [image]

Here are the two formulas I tried:

1. `Float(Int("myraster"*100 + (("myraster" > 0)*2 - 1)*0.5))/100.0`
2. `(Float(Int((["myraster"] * 100) + 0.5)) / 100)`

Comment: IEEE 754 floating-point representation ***cannot*** represent some values, which is why you sometimes get .9999999945 or .0000001 on occassion. The value you see is as close as it gets. There are representation calculators out on the web if you want to see your particular case.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the feedback.